# sorting a python multi-dimensional array?

Tags: python, numpy

I declared a multidimensional array that can accept different data types using `numpy`

`count_array = numpy.empty((len(list), 2), dtype = numpy.object)`

The first array has got strings and the second has got numbers. I want to sort both the columns on the basis of the numbers ...

Is there any easier way like `sort()` method to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [argsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) the second column, then use so-called "fancy-indexing" on the rows:

```
import numpy as np
count_array = np.array([('foo',2),('bar',5),('baz',0)], dtype = np.object)
print(count_array)
# [[foo 2]
#  [bar 5]
#  [baz 0]]

idx = np.argsort(count_array[:, 1])
print(idx)
# [2 0 1]

print(count_array[idx])
# [[baz 0]
#  [foo 2]
#  [bar 5]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider making your array a *structured array* instead:

```
count_array = np.empty((len(list),), dtype=[('str', 'S10'), ('num', int)])
```

Then you can just sort by a specific key:

```
np.sort(arr, order='num')
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose this one:

First, like unutbu, I would use `numpy.array` to build list

```
import numpy as np
count_array = np.array([('foo',2),('bar',5),('baz',0)], dtype = np.object)
```

Then, I sort using `operator.itemgetter`:

```
import operator
newlist = sorted(count_array, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

which means: sort `count_array` w.r.t. argument with index 1, that is the integer value.

Output is

```
[array([baz, 0], dtype=object), array([foo, 2], dtype=object), array([bar, 5], dtype=object)]
```

that I can rearrange. I do this with

```
np.array([list(k) for k in newlist], dtype=np.object)
```

and I get a numpy array with same format as before

```
array([[baz, 0],
       [foo, 2],
       [bar, 5]], dtype=object)
```

In the end, whole code looks like that

```
import numpy as np
import operator

count_array = np.array([('foo',2),('bar',5),('baz',0)], dtype = np.object)

np.array([list(k) for k in sorted(count_array, key=operator.itemgetter(1))], dtype=np.object)
```

with last line doing the requested sort.